# How to "git rebase master" in SVN?

Tags: svn, version-control

Scenario:

- A branch is created (maybe some commits added, in my case none)
- Later, in trunk, a commit is pushed by another developer, that is essential for the branch to work

What is the cleanest workflow to get the commit from trunk?

Comment: I only know [merging](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.branchmerge.html). You are asking for a clean way... Do you have a current method that doesn't satisfy you?

Comment: @ Álvaro G. Vicario, delete the branch and star anew. I do not fully understand SVN's merging. When I merge, only the modifications to files are taken, not the commits (and their messages). This is an unlean way too, to have two commits with the same modifications but different commits and numbers.

Comment: @Vorac : SVN doesn't work the same way as Git does. If you want a versioning system that works like Git, use Git. If you use SVN, you'll have to learn and accept te way SVN works.

Comment: @JB Nizet, no doubt this is true. So I would gleefully accept an answer, stating "no, your thinking is wrong. The workflow in this situation would be this :"

Comment: You already have your answer: start anew if the branch doesn't contain anything yet, or merge from trunk to the branch. To understand why you get two different commits and how merge works in SVN, read the freely available SVN book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `svn merge` to merge changes from one branch to another. This is similar to the `git rebase` command:

```
$ svn co $REPO/branch/$branch/$project
$ cd $project
$ svn merge $REPO/trunk/$project
$ svn commit -m"Merging some change that was in trunk that the branch needs"
```

In the latest revision of Subversion, you no longer need the `-reintegrate` switch.

If you know the exact revision you want to merge. That is, you looked at `svn log` and see the change you want on trunk, you can specify just to merge just that revision:

```
$ svn co $REPO/branch/$branch/$project
$ cd $project
$ svn merge -r$rev $REPO/trunk/$project
$ svn commit -m"Merging revision $rev into branch because the branch needs it"
```

This will only merge in the single change that was checked into `trunk` that the branch also needs.

For more information, use the command `svn help merge` and see the [Subversion online manual](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html).

Remember that `git` has at least two separate repositories it uses, thus, `rebase` and `merge` are both needed while `svn` only deals with the centralized repository, thus only one command is needed.

Comment: even in no-so-latest version of SVN `-reintegrate` switch is not needed here, it would be needed if we merge changes from branch to trunk

Comment: Thanks David, I'll do that!